# React - get DOM element TEXT value with Ref

Tags: reactjs, ref

This should be a simple operation, but everything I keep finding online is how to get an 'input value' with a react ref.

I need to know how to get a TEXT value from a DOM element like

```
<p>hello world</p>
```

and get 'hello world'

I have the ref set properly and I can log the full html tag with refName.current.

To get the text I have tried refName.value, refName.current.value refName.text, refName.current.text(),  refName.innerText.. etc.

Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Thanks.

Comment: `innerText` should work, but why do you need this? Could you show us a snippet where this doesn't actually work?

Comment: current.innerText or current.value.innerText?

Comment: current.innerText works, I must have tried calling it current.innerText(). Any idea why this doesn't come up as a method when I start typing it in VS Code?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can access the text via `ref.current.innerText`

For example ([sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/kind-darkness-z75x3?file=/src/App.js:122-212)):

```
  const ref = useRef();

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log(ref.current?.innerText || "ref not set!");
  }, []);

  return <p ref={ref}>Hello world</p>;
```

Keep in mind that the `ref.current` is not set for the first render - so it is undefined to start with.